# Where can I find any recording of Roger Zelazny's voice on the Internet?

Tags: online-resources, roger-zelazny

I'm a big fan of Roger Zelazny's work and, be it weird, I'd love to hear how he sounded. I've looked far and wide and was unable to find any resource though.

Are there any freely-available-to-everyone or available-to-everyone-who-pays clips of Roger Zelazny voice, preferably reading his own novels?

Comment: As awesome as this question is, I'm not sure this is on-topic. Comments anyone?

Comment: This seem apropos to me: the sci-fi/fantasy author's voice is a critical part of the texture of the canon of their work. Any LotR (books) fan who has heard Tolkien reading the part of the Two Towers where the Ents march off to war against Isengard may have experienced this. :)

Comment: @MrLister - This would fall very nicely into the category of "[Behind-the-scenes and fandom information](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)". As such it's definitely on topic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Youtube has the [Chronicles of Amber, read by Roger Zelazny](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ruSIKXqz33g&index=1&list=PLdGOtyEVx_QoNhyz4SmdDlKZHNMYnTJYo). This link is to Nine Princes in Amber, but will play through the entire series.

Comment: My life is complete now!

Comment: Link broken now, alas!

Answer (score 7):

You can watch a video here with Zelazny reading from his own works;

Comment: If you're outside the US might I suggest you install [Hola for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hola-better-internet/gkojfkhlekighikafcpjkiklfbnlmeio?hl=en) or [Hola for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/collections/hola_networks/t/) allowing you to view it from any location.